# How to merge multiple objects as separate objects

Tags: javascript

I am using Vue.js and I have 2 objects that I would like to combine together but to keep them separated.

I tried to use a spread such as var obj1 = {...obj2, ...obj3} but realized that this was overwriting values because names were the same. I changed the billing address information to have "billing" in front of them and using that same process again, its just a very long list and not very clean to me.

Below are the 2 objects that I am trying to combine.

```
deliveryAddress: {
                firstName: null,
                lastName: null,
                companyName: null,
                jobTitle: null,
                address1: null,
                address2: null,
                city: null,
                country: null,
                province: null,
                region: null,
                state: null,
                zipCode: null,
                phoneNumber: null,
                email: null
            },
billingAddress: {
                billingDifferentFromDelivery: false,
                billingAddress1: null,
                billingAddress2: null,
                billingCity: null,
                billingCountry: null,
                billingState: null,
                billingProvince: null,
                billingZipCode: null,
            }
```

I would like to combine these as either an object with both objects or as an array with both objects. Maybe something similar to this

```
var addressInformation = {
deliveryAddress: {
                firstName: null,
                lastName: null,
                companyName: null,
                jobTitle: null,
                address1: null,
                address2: null,
                city: null,
                country: null,
                province: null,
                region: null,
                state: null,
                zipCode: null,
                phoneNumber: null,
                email: null
            },
billingAddress: {
                billingDifferentFromDelivery: false,
                billingAddress1: null,
                billingAddress2: null,
                billingCity: null,
                billingCountry: null,
                billingState: null,
                billingProvince: null,
                billingZipCode: null,
            }
}
```

or

```
var addressInformation = [{
deliveryAddress: {
                firstName: null,
                lastName: null,
                companyName: null,
                jobTitle: null,
                address1: null,
                address2: null,
                city: null,
                country: null,
                province: null,
                region: null,
                state: null,
                zipCode: null,
                phoneNumber: null,
                email: null
            },
billingAddress: {
                billingDifferentFromDelivery: false,
                billingAddress1: null,
                billingAddress2: null,
                billingCity: null,
                billingCountry: null,
                billingState: null,
                billingProvince: null,
                billingZipCode: null,
            }
}]
```

is this possible? is there a better way to clean this up when combining objects?

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic, you can create a function that accepts objects as parameters. Loop through those objects then insert each one into an empty array or object then return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign property name separately

```
 let addressInformation = {deliveryAddress : ...obj1, billingAddress: ...obj2}
```

or

```
 let addressInformation = [{deliveryAddress : ...obj1}, {billingAddress: ...obj2}]
```

Or if you don't need a new copy then you can do something like this as well

```
  let addressInformation = {deliveryAddress, billingAddress}
```

Comment: This was perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
let addressInformation = {
    deliveryAddress,
    billingAddress
}
```

with  es6 there is no need for `{key:value}` when both the key and the value variable have thesame name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't spread your objs.

```js
const obj1 = {name: 1}
const obj2 = {name: 2}
const newObj = {obj1, obj2}

// result to `{{name: 1}, {name: 2}}` on newObj
```

But I'm not sure about the question

/!\ Keep in mind this not a copy object.